# How do I call a web service from javascript

Tags: javascript, web-services

Say I have a web service http://www.example.com/webservice.pl?q=google which returns text "google.com". I need to call this web service (http://www.example.com/webservice.pl) from a JavaScript module with a parameter (q=google) and then use the return value ("google.com") to do further processing.

What's the simplest way to do this? I am a total JavaScript newbie, so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at one of the many javascript libraries out there. I'd recommend [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com), personally. Aside from all the fancy UI stuff they can do, it has really good [cross-browser AJAX libraries](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax).

```
$.get(
    "http://xyz.com/webservice.pl",
    { q : "google" },
    function(data) {
        alert(data);  // "google.com"
    }
);
```

Answer (score 14):

**EDIT:**

It has been a decade since I answered this question and we now have support for cross-domain XHR in the form of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

For any modern app consider using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to make your requests. If you need support for older browsers you can add a [polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch).

**Original answer:**

Keep in mind that you cannot make requests across domains.  For example, if your page is on yourexample.com and the web service is on myexample.com you cannot make a request to it directly.

If you do need to make a request like this then you will need to set up a proxy on your server.  You would make a request to that proxy page, and it will retrieve the data from the web service and return it to your page.

Comment: i want to get data  form other site without using proxy, are there solution to resolcve this problem

Comment: @AyoubBenayache, yes, you have to implement CORS headers (which weren't available when this answer was written a decade ago). There is a ton of good information about this if you just search CORS.