# How to call json api and and add it to html page via node.js

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js

Im sorry if this may be a dumb question but i hit a wall and been trying to figure this out for hours.

How to call json api and and add it to html page via node.js

my api address is localhost:8080/api I'm routing my html page to index.html. 
I'm guessing it to make son an array and then call array in html? I have n idea how to do that.
please help me out. thanks.

server.js`

```
var util = require('./util.js');

//call random gen - return string with 9 length.
var output = util.stringGen(9);

console.log(output);


var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

// viewed at http://localhost:8080
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});


app.get('/api', function(req, res){
    res.json({healthy: output})
});
```

app.listen(8080);

Comment: What are you using to do the API call?

Comment: Are you asking about making an api call in Javascript and displaying response on html page?

Comment: this is my server.js 

var util = require('./util.js');

//call random gen - return string with 9 length.
var output = util.stringGen(9);

console.log(output);


var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

// viewed at http://localhost:8080
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});


app.get('/api', function(req, res){
    res.json({healthy: output})
});

app.listen(8080);

Comment: ok i added my server.js

Comment: @RohanKumar yes i am

Comment: @Baruch i added my server.js

Comment: @Froggy actually we need to see your client code, show us how you are using the API, your client-side javascript

Comment: for hitting api you should use request module. But, what do you mean by call array in html? Or do  you want to hit api on client side?

Comment: Thats what I'm asking how to make the client of what I'm doing.

Comment: hit api on clientside

Comment: @RohanKumar I'm trying hit api on client side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I call a web service from javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118565/how-do-i-call-a-web-service-from-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is how to call your server from your client.

You might choose different approaches depending on what client you are using.

For native javascript, you can try reading [here](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-EID4t/0/1?curriculum_id=5122e3cbb5827b93e2000865) or if you are using AngularJS, see how to use [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

The URL you would want to call is `http://localhost:8080/api'

Answer (score 0):

To hit api on client side, you need to use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) . I've added a simple example of how to do that using github api and displaying the response in the label field. Although you can display response in any way you want :

```
<body>
<script>

function httpGet(theURL) {
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.open("GET", theURL);
  xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  xmlHttp.send(null);


  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var response = null;
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      response = xmlHttp.responseText;
      document.getElementById("response").value = response;
    }
  };
}

</script>

<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="get Data" 
  onclick="httpGet('https://api.github.com/search/users?q=rohankanojia')" />

<br>
Response : <input id="response" type="label"/>
</body>
```